# JQuery Mobile - link from external page (SinglePage-template) to an internal page (MultiPage-template)

Tags: asp.net, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery mobile site, which uses both, [multi-page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/multipage-template.html) and [single-page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-template.html) approaches. Now I got stuck at a linking problem: when I am on an "external" single page, how do I refer to a "internal" page, which is somewhere inside a multi-page template?

My Multipage-template looks like that:

```
<body>
    <div id="mulitpage-wrapper">
        <msc:mobileHome />
        <msc:mobileTestDirectory />
        <msc:mobileContactUs />
    </div>
</body>
```

A page inside is wrapped like that:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
     ...Some Header, Content and Footer...
</div>
```

I've read about [linking](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html) in JQuery Mobile and I've already tried to link it like an anchor by wrapping the msc tags in divs with name and id tags. I've also tried to anchor the "home" id of the sub page of the multi-page, looking something like this:

```
<a href="../mobile/index.asp#home">link</a>
```

How do I achieve to link "mobileHome" from an external page in this code example?

One more thing: when I hover over it Firefox shows the correct link and when I copy paste that, the browser loads the correct view...

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the attribute `rel="external"` to your link:

```
<a href="../mobile/index.asp#home" rel="external>link</a>
```

Have a try a let me know if this works for you :)